# In terms of iphone application, the way to reload displayed page automatically when a background app comes back to be active

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova

I have developed an iphone application with Phonegap/Cordova v1.9.0.

I  want to realize the following matter.

-When a background app comes back to be active(When the app icon is tapped), a displayed page is reloaded automatically-

Probably I should make some programs in a function, (void)applicationDidBecomeActive, in Appdelegate.m or MainViewController.m, but I have no idea what to do.

Please tell me how to solve this case.

Comment: What is this page in the `UIViewController`? It is from the web (like a web page), or a `UITableView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `NSNotification` observer pattern. In your `MainViewController.m` file, and `viewDidLoad`, you can add an observer (registering for notifications):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(appDidBecomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Then you must implement `appDidBecomeActive:` (you can give the selector any name, but you must implement a method of that name). In this example:

```
- (void)appDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"App became active");
}
```

When the app is resumed, and should this view controller be active, it will simply log that to the console. You can put any code you wish inside that method (in your case, refreshing a page).

Don't forget to remove the observer when the view controller is deallocated in the `dealloc` method. This will remove all observers for you.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    NSLog(@"Removed all notification observers");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I  want to know how to write  a code for "refreshing a page"(the part of "NSLog(@"App became active");" in your middle code). I use Phonegap , so the file type of the page is "html"( not external website).

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using version 1.9?

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);

function onResume() {
    // Handle the resume event, reload the page or content
}
```